# A table row is causing content adding to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code below which works fine when it comes to adding text from a modal window into a textarea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var plusbutton_clicked;

function insertQuestion(form) {

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $plusrow = $("<td class='plusrow'></td>");
    var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");


    $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

    $question.append($questionText);

    });

        $('.plusimage').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $plusimagerow = $("<a onclick='return plusbutton(this);'><img src='Images/plussign.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='imageplus'/></a>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

    $plusrow.append($plusimagerow);

    });

    $tr.append($plusrow);
    $tr.append($question);
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    form.questionText.value = "";

    $('.questionTextArea').val('');


}


function closewindow() {     

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
} 

$('.plusimage').live('click', function() {
    plusbutton($(this));
});


function plusbutton(plus_id) {
    // Set global info
    plusbutton_clicked = plus_id;
    // Display an external page using an iframe
    var src = "previousquestions.php";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
    return false;
}


function addwindow(questionText) { 

    if(window.console) console.log();

    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 
        $('#mainTextarea').val(questionText); 
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);
            }

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
} 


</script>
```

But the problem is that if I include this code below which I need into the `function insertQuestion(form) {`, then it stops the text adding into the textarea, why is it doing this?

```
var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>" );

...

$tr.append($qid);
```

$qid is the question number for each row, so everytime a row is added, it adds a question number by plus 1 each time.

Blow is the html code of where it appends the textarea from the top into a table row:

```
<table id="question">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Question Number <span class="questionNum">1</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="num_questions" name="numQuestion" value="1">
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">
        <textarea class="questionTextArea" id="mainTextarea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE:

I have included links to both applications. One that works but does not include $qid, and one that includes $qid and doesn't work but which I do need working. Please follow steps in both applications so you can test it yourself and see what is happening:

[Application 1](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php): No $qid but working.

[Aplication 2](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php): Contains $qid but not working:

Follow steps below for both applications:

1. Click on "Add Question" button, then will add a textarea within a new row.
2. Click on the "Green Plus" button within the table row you just added, a modal window will appear.
3. In modal window it displays a search bar, in search bar type in "AAA" and click on "Search" button
4. Results will appear of your search, click on "Add" button to add a row. You will find out modal window is closed but the content from the "Question" field is not added in the textarea within the row you clicked on the green plus button

Comment: can you add the HTML code please

Comment: Here is html code of textarea and question number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicity setting the td value with

```
var $qid = $("<td class='qid'></td>" ).text(qnum);  
$tr.append($qid);
```

And then replace the text setting code from

```
$(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);
```

to

```
$(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);
```

Comment: Ok, when I tried your code, then it did not solve the problem. but if I remove `$tr.append($qid);`, then it adds the content within the textarea. But I no need `$tr.append($qid);` This is strange.

Comment: I included html code in my question, this might help you with your answer but im not sure?

Comment: I have added code to find and set the text in textarea.Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it easily if you try with text:

```
var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>"+ qnum + "</td>" );  
$tr.append($qid);
```

or

```
$("<td class='qid'></td>" ).text('hello').appendTo($tr);
```

Comment: If I do this then it messes up with display on page as it displays the text in like 3 different areas. I will show you url of both applications, one that is working but that doesn't contain $qid, and one that contains $qid but isn't working, give me 5 mins.

Comment: @user1421767 please check `$('tr')` should be `$tr`, I update that

Comment: Ok, this has corrected it and allow textareas to append content, only 1 tiny problem, the columns I have goes as 'plusrow', 'Question Number' and 'Question'. But the problem is that 'Question Number' is going under 'plusrow' column and 'plusrow' is going under 'Question Number'. How do I get them in the right column if I am doing it with your method